# How to add an image in the Richeditor plugin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, plugins, rich-text-editor

I am trying to add an image inside the Richeditor plugin of Flutter. Can someone tell me how to accomplish the task? I have attached what I have been doing bellow

```
RichEditor(
        key: keyEditor,
        value: 'initial html here',
        editorOptions: RichEditorOptions(
          placeholder: 'Start typing',
          // backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey, // Editor's bg color
          // baseTextColor: Colors.white,
          // editor padding
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          // font name
          baseFontFamily: 'sans-serif',
          // Position of the editing bar (BarPosition.TOP or BarPosition.BOTTOM)
          barPosition: BarPosition.TOP,
        ),
        // You can return a Link (maybe you need to upload the image to your
        // storage before displaying in the editor or you can also use base64
        getImageUrl: (image) {
          String link = 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/24323581?v=4';
          String base64 = base64Encode(image.readAsBytesSync());
          String base64String = 'data:image/png;base64, $base64';
          return base64String;
        },
      )
```

Comment: Could you please explain more?